# ask for confirmation before closing emulator in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there a way I can disable close button of the android emulator or get a confirmation before closing.
After several runs I accidently closed the emulator.
Also it takes a lot of time to load the emulator again.

Comment: you can try other emulators like genymotion

Answer (score 0):

**There is no built-in support anywhere for this. You have to search for 3rd-party solutions.**

Here is one I found quickly.. http://lifehacker.com/5183947/noclose-disables-windows-close-button.

Go to the website, let it load, and then you have to search for `NoClose`. It is there, but it does not scroll automatically to the app to download.

You can also try to search for another similar solution.